# Inputing multiple emails (inline), inviting existing and new users with Rails and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I followed an example in codepen to input multiple emails to invite people to join my website..

Here is the link to codepen example:
https://codepen.io/hariom15791/pen/vGqXQG

I use slim.

Problem:
I enter multiple emails, but when I click the button send i get empty array sent to the database.

The code works without jQuery with adding multiple emails with comma. But when I add the jQuery plugin, it just send empty array.

Here is the invite form:

```
= simple_form_for @invite, remote: true do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

  .form-inputs
    .col-sm-12.email-id-row.all-mail
      span.to-input To

      = f.hidden_field :trip_id, value: @invite.trip_id
      / = f.input :email, id: "email", placeholder: "enter email and enter"
      = f.input :email, as: :text, autocomplete: "off", id: "email", input_html: { multiple: true }, placeholder: "Enter multiple emails and enter"



  .form-actions
    button.btn.btn-primary type="submit" Send
    = link_to "Cancel", trip_path(@trip), class: 'btn btn-default space-left'
```

The controller for invite:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def new
    trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @invite = @trip.invites.build
  end

  def create
    email = params[:invite][:email].try(:split, ', ')
    email.each do |email|
      @invite = Invite.new(invite_params) # Make a new Invite
      @invite.email = email
      @invite.sender_id = current_user.id # set the sender to the current user

      if @invite.save
        #if the user already exists
        if @invite.recipient != nil
          #send a notification to existing new_user
          InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite, new_user_session_path).deliver
          #add user to the trip
          @invite.recipient.trips.push(@invite.trip)

        else
         InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver #send the invite data to our mailer to deliver the email

        end

    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks, invitation has successfully been sent"
      format.html { redirect_to trips_path }
      format.json {redirect_to trips_path }
      format.js
    end

  end

  private

    def invite_params
      params.require(:invite).permit(:email, :recipient_id, :trip_id, :member_id, :sender_id, :token)
    end

end
```

The javascript:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.easing/js/jquery.easing.js
//= require bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
//= require grayscale.js
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require chosen
//= require toastr
//= require jquery.email.multiple
//= require bootstrap-tagsinput
//= require_tree .



$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  $("#invite_email").keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
        //alert('You Press enter');
       var getValue = $(this).val();

       $('.all-mail').append('<span class="email-ids">'+ getValue +' <span class="cancel-email">x</span></span>');
       $(this).val(' ');
       console.log(this)
      }
  });

  // Cancel
  $(document).on('click','.cancel-email',function(){

    $(this).parent().remove();

  });

});
```

The SCSS for invite:

```
span.email-ids {
    float: left;
    /* padding: 4px; */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
span.cancel-email {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 18px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 49%;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 1px;    cursor: pointer;
}
.col-sm-12.email-id-row {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.col-sm-12.email-id-row input {
    border: 0px; outline:0px;
}
span.to-input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
.col-sm-12.email-id-row {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin-top: 23px;
}
```

Here is the form with some entry:
[image]

and here is the sent invite with empty array!

> From: trip@example.com Subject: Trip Invitation Date: Jul 19, 2019
>   08:53:11 PM PDT To: [" \r\n"] Welcome to trip.com, [" \r\n"]
>
> Trip request ,your email is: [" \r\n"].
>
> To sign up to the site, just follow this link:
>   localhost:3000/users/sign_up?invite_token=bb785bee37e24dffa62ca4fb144b2c74eab9510a
>
> Thanks for joining and have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good solution for my question. I used the following gem for rails 5:
bootstrap-tokenfield-rails

Refer to github below:
https://github.com/icicletech/bootstrap-tokenfield-rails

This was by far a simpler solution than the jQuery and other suggested ones.

Answer (score 0):

You do `$(this).val('');`, it clears input's value. You have to store inputted emails in a hidden input.

```
var emails = [];

$(".enter-mail-id").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
    //alert('You Press enter');
    var getValue = $(this).val().trim();
    if (getValue) {
      $('.all-mail').append('<span class="email-ids">' + getValue + ' <span class="cancel-email" data-email-to-cancel="' + getValue + '">x</span></span>');
      emails.push(getValue)
      $(".to-submit-id").val(emails.join(','))
      $(this).val('');
    }
  }
});

/// Cancel 

$(document).on('click', '.cancel-email', function() {
  var toCancel = $(this).data('email-to-cancel');
  $(this).parent().remove();
  emails = emails.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem != toCancel;
  });
  $(".to-submit-id").val(emails.join(','))
});

// $('.enter-mail-id').click()
```

```html
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="to_sumbit" class="to-submit-id"  /> -->
<input type="text" name="to_sumbit" class="to-submit-id"  />
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgGxoz

Instead of implementing such UI component from scratch, I recommend to use [select2](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes)

Comment: Thanks for your information. I thought select2 is used to select items from a table. In my case the emails do not exist so they must be entered.

Comment: select2 seems to work with tag fields. Please go carefully through all examples on this page: https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes

If you don't like select2, there are dozens of similar jquery plugins: https://www.google.by/search?q=jquery+tags+input

Comment: Hi Stanislav: Tried several ways with select2 (which i like) but could not make it work adding multiple emails which could work with the following line in my invite controller: email = params[:invite][:email].try(:split, ', '). Also, i have change one  line in the form to be as follow: = f.email_field :email, as: :text, class: "my_input". So please let me know how you would you code it to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: I can simply invite many user by adding email with (, ) and it works. But it does not have jQuery effect.